# Abstraction for Throttling API Calls

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to write a convenient abstraction to thottle api calls.  The API calls will be some kind of HTTP request.  I want to be able to write all the app logic as if I were just in the `IO` Monad but then have the abstraction throttle the calls for me so I don't surpass some predefined limit.  Having these calls run asynchronously would be nice.  Right now I have this.

```
data APICallStats = APICallStats                                                  
    {                                                                             
      startTime     :: !UTCTime                                                   
    , requestCount  :: !Int                                                       
    , tps           :: !Int                                                       
    } deriving Show                                                               

newtype APICall a = APICall (IO a)                                                

initStats :: Int -> IO APICallStats                                               
initStats limit = APICallStats <$> getCurrentTime <*> pure 0 <*> pure limit         


makeCall :: MVar APICallStats -> APICall a -> IO a                                  
makeCall mv (APICall f) = do                                                      
    (APICallStats st c t) <- readMVar mv                                          
    now <- getCurrentTime                                                         

    let inSeconds = realToFrac (diffUTCTime now st) :: Double                     
        cp1 = fromIntegral (c+1)                                                  
        td = fromIntegral t                                                       
    when (cp1 / inSeconds > td)                                                   
        (threadDelay (round $ (cp1 / td - inSeconds)*1000000))                    

    modifyMVar_ mv
         (\(APICallStats start req ts) -> return $ APICallStats start (req+1) ts)

    f
```

And I can test it like this.  And it works fine in a single or multiple threads because of the `MVar`.

```
testCall :: String -> APICall ()                                                    
testCall id = APICall (getCurrentTime >>= (putStrLn . ((++) (id ++ " ")) . show)) 

test :: IO ()                                                                       
test = do                                                                           
    mv <- initStats 1 >>= newMVar                                                   
    forever $ makeCall mv (testCall "")                                             

threadedTest :: IO ()                                                               
threadedTest = do                                                                   
    mv <- initStats 1 >>= newMVar                                                   
    threadId <- forkIO $ forever $ makeCall mv (testCall "thread0")                 
    forever $ makeCall mv (testCall "main thread")                                  
    killThread threadId
```

This is nice and all but it is not as abstract as I want it to be.  Since there will only be a couple specific API calls I can have them return the type `APICall a`.  And then make this a monad that is an instance of `MonadIO` so I can just write my logic and use `liftIO` when I need to.  But I'm unsure if I would be able to make this a monad that didn't break the laws and how exactly to go about it.

**EDIT**

I think I've gotten pretty close to what I want it to do.

```
withThrottle :: Int -> StateT (MVar APICallStats) IO a -> IO a                      
withThrottle limit f = do                                                           
    mv <- initStats limit >>= newMVar                                               
    evalStateT f mv                                                                 

process :: APICall a -> StateT (MVar APICallStats) IO a                             
process a = do                                                                      
    mv <- get                                                                       
    liftIO $ makeCall mv a
```

With this I can write something like this.

```
stateTest = do                                                                    
    withThrottle 2 $ do                                                           
        process (testCall "")                                                     
        process (testCall "")                                                     
        process (testCall "")                                                     
        liftIO $ threadDelay 10000000   -- Some long computation                                            
        process (testCall "")                                                       
        process (testCall "")                                                       
        process (testCall "")                                                       
        process (testCall "")
```

With a long running app the entire thing can run is this monad.  This will guarantee that It doesn't make too many outside API calls over the lifetime of the service. I just don't want the state monad.  Just something that is `MonadIO`.  So I think I just need to hide that and I'll be done.  But the solution isn't very pretty so other suggestions welcome.

Comment: Don't worry too much about making a fancy type; if you are writing code in `IO`, there's nothing that will stop a developer (you) from writing their own `IO` implementation of the API call that gets around the `newtype APICall`. If you make a new monad that is an instance of `MonadIO`, a developer can still dig up the underlying `IO` monad to make the API calls themselves.

Comment: @Cirdec If the Constructor of `APICall` was not exported how would they do this?  Yes, they could do this but then they would need to read the api spec and everything.  I don't think the abstraction i'm looking for is supposed to be bullet proof.  They could always just set the limit to a very high number to avoid the throttling.

Comment: Exactly; since you can't stop them from "reading the api spec and everything", don't bother trying too much. It's a convenience for you, not a property any type system can guarantee.  If you are looking for convenience, you could encapsulate what's going on a bit more. Consider a type like `type Scheduler m = forall a. APICall a -> m a`. If you want to mess around with a monad transformer stack you could write `class (Monad m) => MonadApiCall m where schedule :: APICall a -> m a`. The former has the advantage that you can have more than one scheduler.

Comment: Since `APICall` is just a newtype wrapper around `IO`, and presumably you intend to `derive` the `Monad` instance... it's really just the `IO` monad with another name. What laws are you worried about going wrong? Or do you intend to write a `Monad` instance by hand, and if so, what would it do?

Comment: @DanielWagner Check edits.  I think Cirdec is right that it should probably be a monad transformer stack.  I used `StateT` in my example.  I either have to hide that from the user or write my own.

Comment: It seems that you don't need `StateT` and that `ReaderT` would be enough. You never change the state, you only modify what's inside `MVar`, but the `MVar` remains the same.